# Map a class individual to another class using Jess in protege

Tags: ontology, protege, jess

Is there any possibility to map an existing individual of a class to another class with Protege functions in Jess?  The function make-instance creates new instance, while modify-instance allows instance slot updates. But, I would like to use an existing class instance to make it as an instance of another class?

Comment: Your doesn't make sense. An instance of a class is just that, an object of the class. If you want an object of another class, create it from that class.

Comment: If you have a rule IF THEN , IF some cause then m1 is Ham else m1 is Spam and given that Ham and Spam are 2 classes  and given that the causes change then you need to modify the class to which the m1 belongs to so it makes sense in rule based applications.

Comment: An instance of a class is just that, an object of the class. If you want an object of another class, create it from that class. Facts in Jess (like objects in Java) are instances of a class. Dealing with subclasses of the same parent classes may be achieved to a degree but basically no change of the original class can be effected.